# How to add method to a class (Helper function)?

Tags: c++, c++11, non-member-functions

How can I add my own method to a pre-existing class without any change in context of pre-existing class.

for example :

```
   A.hpp
        class A
        {
        public :
        void print1()
        {
          cout << "print1";
        }
        };

    B.hpp
        //add a helper function to class A
        //for example:
        A::print2()
        {
        cout << "print2";
        }

     main.cpp

        #include "A.hpp"
        #include "B.hpp"
        main()
        {
           A a1;
           a1.print2();
        }
```

Comment: [Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)? [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)?

Answer (score 5):

To extend a class in C++, distinguish two cases.

If the new function can be expressed in terms of the current interface, use **non-member functions**

```
// B.hpp
void print2(A const& a)
{
    // pre-call extensions (logging, checking etc.)
    a.print1();
    // post-call extensions (logging, checking etc.)
}
```

If the new function requires knowledge about the current implementation, use **class inheritance**

```
// B.hpp
// WARNING: here be dragons, read on before using this in production code
class B: public A
{
public:
    void print2() const // compiler-generated signature: void print2(B const*)
    {
        // pre-call extensions (logging, checking etc.)
        print1();
        // post-call extensions (logging, checking etc.)
    }
};
```

However, deriving from a class that was not intended to be a base class, can be dangerous. In particular, if `A` does not have a `virtual` destructor, you can get into trouble if you ever use pointers to dynamically allocated `B` objects in places where they would be deallocated as if they were pointers to `A` objects.

Furthermore, because `A::print1()` was not made `virtual`, you get into all sorts of name hiding problems, which is why you have to name the extended function `B::print2()`.

**Long story short**: know which kind of classes you are writing. If you want to extend the behavior based on a class implementation, then you better make it suitable as a base class (virtual destructor, virtual functions that you can override). Otherwise, mark your class as `final` (new C++11 contextual keyword). This will generate compiler warnings if you try to override existing functions.

**NOTE**: In other languages (notably D), it is possible to let the compiler automatically find non-member functions `print2(a)` when it sees the syntax `a.print2()`. Unfortunately, such **uniform function call syntax** is not on the roadmap yet for C++.

Comment: In the delphi compiler when we need to increase the ability of class( do not have the source) we can write a helper function for class.this helper function is similar to static function and to public properties has access.

Comment: This answer is a very long form of the word "no"... but +1.